# unzipping the file using cypress

Tags: javascript, node.js, cypress, unzip

[image]I need to unzip the file using 'unzipping' whereas I am using the below code to do the same but it is partially unzipping but it is throwing an Invalid path error (as path contains special character *).please help me to fix it

```
let path = 'cypress/downloads/'
let file = '910-00001.1-20220419-1843.zip'

describe('example unzip', () => {
  it(' test', () => {
    cy.task('unzipping', { path, file })
    })





//task code (Added it into plugins --> index.js)

const unzipping = require('./unzipping')

module.exports = (on, config) => {
    on('task', {
        'unzipping': unzipping.unzip,
    })
}
```

//   ./unzipping file (created a file named unzipping.js inside plugin folder)

```
const decompress = require('decompress');

const unzip = ({ path, file }) => decompress(path + file, path + 'unzip/' + file.replace('.zip', ''))

module.exports = {
    unzip,
}
```

Comment: It would be helpful if you could show your task code.

Comment: const unzipping = require('./unzipping')

module.exports = (on, config) => {
    on('task', {
        'unzipping': unzipping.unzip,
    })
}

Comment: The problem is inside your `'./unzipping'` module. All the Cypress code you posted looks ok.

Comment: , Now
const decompress = require('decompress');

const unzip = ({ path, file }) => decompress(path + file, path + 'unzip/' + file.replace('.zip', ''))

module.exports = {
    unzip,
}

Comment: could u please check I have added the unzipping file @Fody

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, I tried all your code you gave above, and it worked perfectly.

The only thing I can think if is the contents of the zip is the problem. In my test I made a simple zip with two text files `1.txt` and `2.txt`, then running the test, found them in the folder `/cypress/downloads/unzip/910-00001.1-20220419-1843`.

I suggest you do the same with a dummy zip, if the code works then look at the contents of `910-00001.1-20220419-1843.zip`.

Comment: 910-00001.1-20220419-1843.zip ,issue is with file path only @Fody,it contains special characters